# What is the method to right click using the keyboard on Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard, high-sierra

How do I get the option's menu using only keyboard shortcuts that could help me correct the spellings while typing?

[image]

Comment: wich version of MacOS? Which Mac model? Any particular program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context menu can primarily be opened by a *right mouse click* only.
But via *System Preferences>Universal Access* you can control mouse keys by using the keyboard number pad. When activated, a right mouse click then can be done via the keyboard by using *Ctrl-5* on a keyboard with a numpad or *Fn-Ctrl-I* on a laptop. This will allow you to 'right-click' something.

Go to *System Preference>Universal Access>Mouse>Enable Mouse Keys (ON)*

Position the mouse cursor and hold *Ctrl*.
Press and release the keypad’s *5* key (or *Fn+I*).
Release *Ctrl*.
Make sure to have the mouse pointer properly positioned, otherwise it won’t work.

Comment: thanks! you cleared my concept about how actually it is supposed to work.